# I have multiple OneToMany mappings in a entity. Hibernate loads the first one even without me requesting that object. Is that the expected behaviour?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

MedicalEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_med_area")

public class MedicalEntity {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="med_area_id")
private Integer med_area_id;


@Column(name="med_area_cd")
private String area_code;

@Column(name="area_nm")
private String area_description;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="medical_area_id")
private List<ProviderEntity> resources;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="medAreaId")
private List<FacilityEntity> facility;



public List<ProviderEntity> getResources() {
    return resources;
}

public void setResources(List<ProviderEntity> resources) {
    this.resources = resources;
}

public List<FacilityEntity> getFacility() {
    return facility;
}

public void setFacility(List<FacilityEntity> facility) {
    this.facility = facility;
}

public Integer getMed_area_id() {
    return med_area_id;
}

public void setMed_area_id(Integer med_area_id) {
    this.med_area_id = med_area_id;
}

public String getArea_code() {
    return area_code;
}

public void setArea_code(String area_code) {
    this.area_code = area_code;
}

public String getArea_description() {
    return area_description;
}

public void setArea_description(String area_description) {
    this.area_description = area_description;
}
```

FacilityEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_facility")

public class FacilityEntity implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="facility_id")
private int facilityId;

@Column(name="facility_nm")
private String facilityName;

@Column(name="facility_code")
private String facilityCode;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="facility_id")
private List<ProviderEntity> resources;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="med_area_id")
private MedicalEntity medAreaId;

@Column(name="insert_dt")
private Date insertDt;



public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getFacilityId() {
    return facilityId;
}

public void setFacilityId(int facilityId) {
    this.facilityId = facilityId;
}

public String getFacilityName() {
    return facilityName;
}

public void setFacilityName(String facilityName) {
    this.facilityName = facilityName;
}

public String getFacilityCode() {
    return facilityCode;
}

public void setFacilityCode(String facilityCode) {
    this.facilityCode = facilityCode;
}

public List<ProviderEntity> getResources() {
    return resources;
}

public void setResources(List<ProviderEntity> resources) {
    this.resources = resources;
}

public MedicalEntity getMedAreaId() {
    return medAreaId;
}

public void setMedAreaId(MedicalEntity medAreaId) {
    this.medAreaId = medAreaId;
}

public Date getInsertDt() {
    return insertDt;
}

public void setInsertDt(Date insertDt) {
    this.insertDt = insertDt;
}


public FacilityEntity(Integer id, String facility_name, String facility_code) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.facilityName = facility_name;
    this.facilityCode = facility_code;
}

public FacilityEntity() {
    super();
}
```

}

Provider Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_provider")
public class ProviderEntity implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="provider_id")
private Integer provider_id;

@Column(name="resource_cd")
private String resource_code;

@Column(name="first_nm")
private String first_name;

@Column(name="last_nm")
private String last_name;

@Column(name="middle_nm")
private String middle_name;

@Column(name="title_nm")
private String title;

@Column(name="department_nm")
private String department_name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="home_med_area_id")
private MedicalEntity medical_area_id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="home_facility_id")
private FacilityEntity facility_id;


public Integer getProvider_id() {
    return provider_id;
}

public void setProvider_id(Integer provider_id) {
    this.provider_id = provider_id;
}

public String getResource_code() {
    return resource_code;
}

public void setResource_code(String resource_code) {
    this.resource_code = resource_code;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getMiddle_name() {
    return middle_name;
}

public void setMiddle_name(String middle_name) {
    this.middle_name = middle_name;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDepartment_name() {
    return department_name;
}

public void setDepartment_name(String department_name) {
    this.department_name = department_name;
}

public MedicalEntity getMedical_area_id() {
    return medical_area_id;
}

public void setMedical_area_id(MedicalEntity medical_area_id) {
    this.medical_area_id = medical_area_id;
}

public FacilityEntity getFacility_id() {
    return facility_id;
}

public void setFacility_id(FacilityEntity facility_id) {
    this.facility_id = facility_id;
}

public ProviderEntity() {
    super();

}
```

}

Service Layer:

```
    List<MedicalEntity> result=medicalAreaRepository.findAll();


    //transforming entity into DTO and setting properties based on UI requirements
    for(MedicalEntity medicalEntity:result)
    {

        MedicalDTO medicalDTO=new MedicalDTO();
        medicalDTO.setArea_code(medicalEntity.getArea_code());
        medicalDTO.setArea_description(medicalEntity.getArea_description());
        medicalDTO.setId(medicalEntity.getMed_area_id());
        //System.out.println(medicalEntity.getResources());
        medicalResponse.addElementsToList(medicalDTO);
    }
```

When I call hover over my List result, it automatically fires the query to load the facilities.

Logs which are generated:

Hibernate: select medicalent0_.med_area_id as med_area1_1_, medicalent0_.med_area_cd as med_area2_1_, medicalent0_.area_nm as area_nm3_1_ from t_med_area medicalent0_

2020-02-11 15:26:01.377 TRACE 39096 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll]
2020-02-11 15:26:01.383 TRACE 39096 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@2930e0de] for key [public abstract java.util.List org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.findAll()] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-2]

Hibernate: select z0_.med_area_id as med_area6_0_0_, z0_.id as id1_0_0_, z0_.id as id1_0_1_, z0_.facility_code as facility2_0_1_, z0_.facility_id as facility3_0_1_, z0_.facility_nm as facility4_0_1_, z0_.insert_dt as insert_d5_0_1_, z0_.med_area_id as med_area6_0_1_ from t_facility z0_ where z0_.med_area_id=?

Hibernate: select z0_.med_area_id as med_area6_0_0_, z0_.id as id1_0_0_, z0_.id as id1_0_1_, z0_.facility_code as facility2_0_1_, z0_.facility_id as facility3_0_1_, z0_.facility_nm as facility4_0_1_, z0_.insert_dt as insert_d5_0_1_, z0_.med_area_id as med_area6_0_1_ from t_facility z0_ where z0_.med_area_id=?

Hibernate: select z0_.med_area_id as med_area6_0_0_, z0_.id as id1_0_0_, z0_.id as id1_0_1_, z0_.facility_code as facility2_0_1_, z0_.facility_id as facility3_0_1_, z0_.facility_nm as facility4_0_1_, z0_.insert_dt as insert_d5_0_1_, z0_.med_area_id as med_area6_0_1_ from t_facility z0_ where z0_.med_area_id=?.

My question is: Why is it fetching the details of FacilityEntity?I am not explicitly making any calls to get the properties of FacilityEntity.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'hover' do you mean while debugging? If you inspect any of the lazy elements its akin to accessing them, so hibernate will attempt to lazy load the entity.

Comment: Yes, I mean debugging. If it is trying to access it. Why it does not execute a query for List<ProviderEntity> resources in MedicalEntity?